# MySQL left join shows duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables - 1) users and 2) warehouseMapping.

### users

id, name

### warehouseMapping

id, userId, warehouseId

From the above you can see that "warehouseMapping" table is the mapping table which will show that which warehouseIds are related to a particular user. There will be multiple warehouseIds for an user.

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN warehouseMapping
    ON warehouseMapping.userId = users.id
WHERE 1 AND warehouseMapping.warehouseId IN (1, 2)
```

My intention is to show the users who have the warehouse id 1 and 2.

After submitting the same, MySQL showing me the same user name twice.

Inputs for users table:

```
id                  name
***************************
1                   Niladri
2                   Tanay
```

Inputs for warehouseMapping table:

```
id   userId        warehouseId
*****************************
1      1           1
2      1           2
3      1           3
4      2           1
5      2           2
```

Comment: Please share some input data and expected output along with want actual output you are getting.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - question updated. Please check the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find users who have both warehouses, here is one way:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN warehouseMapping w
    ON w.userId = u.id
WHERE w.warehouseId IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.warehouseId) = 2;
```